# How to replace 0's with blank in kables

Tags: r, kableextra, kable

I'm creating a rather large html table using the kable function, and this table has a lot of 0's in it. In order to only show the relevant information more clearly, I'm trying hide the 0's in the table by just replacing them with blank space.

Right now, I'm trying something like this but it's not working:

```
my_table = knitr::kable(...)
cat(gsub(0," ",my_table), sep = '\n')
```

Something similar to the above works to remove NA's, but I can't seem to get it to work for 0's.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: example data:

```
Product = c('A','B','A','A','C','B')
Month = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Apr', 'Jan', 'Feb')
my_data = data.frame(Product, Month)
my_table = table(my_data)
kable(my_table) #This has the 0's which I don't want

Product | Month

A       | Jan

B       | Feb

A       | Feb

A       | Apr

C       | Jan

B       | Feb
```

Current output:

```
----Jan  Feb  Mar Apr

A  1 1 0 1

B  0 2 0 0

C  1 0 0 0
```

Desired output:

```
----Jan Feb Mar Apr

A 1 1 - 1

B - 2 - -

C 1 - - -
```

except "-" would be a blank space instead of a dash

EDIT2: never mind, I figured it out even though this is really hacky:

```
my_kable = knitr::kable(my_table)
gsub(0, ' ', my_kable)
```

lol

Comment: Can you provide a toy example of what data you're putting into `knitr::kable()`?

Comment: try to quote the 0 - `"0"`

Comment: added a toy example of the kind of data I'm using

Comment: It would be better if you provide it in code so that we can easily import it. e.g. `data.frame("Product" = LETTERS[1:4], etc.)`

Comment: okay, I added some code for a toy dataset

Comment: `my_table[my_table == 0] <- ""`

Comment: `knitr::kable(replace(my_table, my_table==0, ""))`?

Answer (score 3):

The reason your original `gsub` wasn't working was that it was flattening the table to a vector. One of many options to maintain the table structure would be to use the `replace` function:

```
knitr::kable(replace(my_table, my_table==0, ""))

#|   |Apr |Feb |Jan |
#|:--|:---|:---|:---|
#|A  |1   |1   |1   |
#|B  |    |2   |    |
#|C  |    |    |1   |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base `R` `gsub()`:

```
gsub(0, " ", kable(my_table))
```

To get:

```
|   | Apr| Feb| Jan|
|:--|---:|---:|---:|
|A  |   1|   1|   1|
|B  |    |   2|    |
|C  |    |    |   1|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
gsub(" 0", "  ", kable(my_table))
```

Comment: To avoid replacing zeros in non-zero numbers. Also, the 'gsub' solution keeps numbers right-aligned, contrary to the 'replace' solution.